# Keyerror problem when merging a single column from a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes where i want to add a single column from dataframe2 to dataframe1. When I merge them using `dataframe1.merge(dataframe2, on = 'Name')` it works but doesn't add any columns. When I use `dataframe1.merge(dataframe2['AvgUnitPrice'], on = 'Name'`) it gives me `KeyError problem with 'Name'`

Tried different approaches such as

```
dataframe1 = dataframe1.merge(dataframe2[list(prices_df)[2]], left_on = 'Name', right_on = 'Name')
```

and still didn't work. Also replaced all of the spaces inside dataframe1 with '' instead.
Also checked the dtypes of both and both of them are objects.

```
base_df = pd.read_csv(base_dataset_path, encoding = 'ISO-8859-1')
prices_df = pd.read_csv(prices_dataset_path, encoding = 'ISO-8859-1')

#Renaming no name columns 
base_df.rename(columns = {list(base_df)[1] : 'Categories', list(base_df)[2] : 'Name'}, inplace = True)

prices_df.rename(columns = {list(prices_df)[2] : 'AvgUnitPrice'}, inplace = True)

prices_df.rename(columns = {list(prices_df)[1] : 'Name'}, inplace = True)

#replacing white spaces
prices_df['Name'] = prices_df['Name'].str.replace(' ', '')

base_df['Name'] = base_df['Name'].str.replace(' ','')

#Merge
base_df = base_df.merge(prices_df[list(prices_df)[2]], left_on = 'Name', right_on = 'Name')
```

**Expected out put:**

```
dataframe1 merged with dataframe2 only with column AvgUnitPrice on 'Name'
```

**Result:**

```
KeyError 'Name' ##The right_on = 'Name'
```

Comment: After you clean you column headers.  Paste the results of dataframe1.to_dict() and dataframe3.to_dict() to the question.

Comment: I cleaned to headers with
datafram1.columns = datafram1columns.str.strip().str.lower().str.replace(' ', '_').str.strip()
But i'm unable to post the to_dict() since the dataset is more than 50k rows

Comment: Also when using

datafram1_df = datafram1_df.merge(datafram2_df, left_on = 'name', right_on = 'name')

It merges now with all of the columns on name but that isn't what i want i just one a single column which is AvgUnitPrice

Comment: I just want to see you dataframe structure.  dataframe1.head.to_dict() and dataframe2 also.

Answer (score 0):

In your code sample you wrote *#Renaming no name columns*.

This is in contradiction with the way you used *read_csv*.
Since you passed neither *header* nor *names* parameters,
*read_csv* executes the default variant concerning column name
setting, namely *names-'infer'*, i.e. it tries to read them from
the first input line.

So I disagree with your assumption that these column have **no names**.
If they truly had no names then an attempt to rename them should fail.

Note also that `list(base_df)` gives column names as a list, but their numbers
**start from 0**, so `list(base_df)[1]` gives the name of the **second** column.

Hence, using "1-based" column numeration, you rename **second** and **third**
column to *Categories* and *Name*. Is this what you want?

I propose that just before *merge* add to your code:

```
print(base_df.columns, prices_df.columns)
```

so you will know what are actual column names.

Or even better: Print *base_df.head()* and *prices_df.head()*, so you
will have both column names in both tables and content of initial rows.

Maybe, based ot this printout, you will find something weird in your
DataFrames?

Sometimes it happens that the source file has no "column name row",
but starts from actual data rows.
An attempt to *read_csv* such a file the way you did has the result that:

- the content of the first **data** row is used as **column names** (results
  are usually unpredictable),
- the actual data in the DataFrame start from the **second** input row.

As from your code I see, you have "some problems" with columns names,
I have another hint: Call *read_csv* with *names=[...]*. This way you
specify column names on your own. This implies that actual row data
are read from the **initial** row.
If you want to omit this row, pass *skiprows=1* to skip this row.

And after any of these experiments *print(df.head())* to check
column names and data contained in each column.

Yet another hint: After *read_csv* leave only some initial part of
what you have read and drop "further" rows.
This way you can test your code on smaller part of source data.

Then you can incrementally leave bigger number of rows and repeat
your processing. If at some point of this procedure occurs an error,
you should look for the cause in the last "extension part" of your
source data.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time. You gave me different insights on how to approach things.